# How to include Jison into Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jison

How can one include the

> Jison

javascript library into an angular project?

At the moment I'm getting:

> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/jison/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map/source-node.js
>   8:45-52 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in
>   which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

and

> GET http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js
>   net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK) inline.bundle.js:55 Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at
>   **webpack_require** (inline.bundle.js:55)

Comment: Elaborate your question in detail.

Comment: Would you detail which details do I need more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install to your projects package.json

```
npm install jison -s
```

In your tsconfig.app.json include 'node' in your types array within compilerOptions

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
       "node"
    ]
}
```

Then import it in any TypeScript file.

```
import * as jison from 'jison';
```

Comment: I'm getting: `WARNING in ./node_modules/jison/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map/source-node.js
8:45-52 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted`

Comment: and also `GET http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)
inline.bundle.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)`

Comment: I was missing "module": "commonjs" in my tsconfig.json also.